# Reinstalling issues

Tags: installation

For some reason I wanted to reinstall drupal on my local windows 7. I thought it would be simple but its not (at least for me). I simply removed all files from my www root and dropped the db.

When I extracted drupal zip and tried to install.php it's showing me message that drupal already installed and showing message. There is also a notice message saying constant drupal root already defined at line 18.

I have set folder options to show hidden files so there is no chance that I could misses any files. I cleared the browser cache too to make sure the clean install. I don't thing I need to do anything in apache, php or db configurations. Iam using xampp.

It has been nearly 3 days since I am trying but I don't see any clue to proceed further. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure you dropped the correct db? Does it even let you get to the point where you choose the db?

Comment: Clear any opcode caches you're using (apc, zend, etc); if you're using memcache/redis make sure you've flushed those too, or chosen a new prefix in settings.php for the new site. In fact, if you have a sites/default/settings.php at all, delete it

Comment: @brandon dropped correct db. It's very first screen it says drupal already installed.

Comment: @clive I am not sure what opcode caches are, I by my self have not used any of them uneless drupal internally uses it.